# AS3 keeping score

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm making a game where my character passes an object and when doing so the score counts up by one. The object is part of an array, and when I pass the first object the score counts up continuously. Here is what I have so far:

```
if (beardman.x >= tubes[i].x)
{
 score++;
}
```

How would I re-write it so that the score just counts up by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is have a similar array and remove from that list like so:

```
//assume you have a copy of the tubes array called activeTubes.
if (beardman.x >= activeTubes[i].x)
{
    score++;
    activeTubes.splice( i, 1 );
}
```

Edit: I wanted to add that splice is known to be a fairly expensive operation as it shifts how the indices are stored in memory. That being said, if you are searching through a fairly large list a optimization to make would look like this:

```
//assume you have a copy of the tubes array called activeTubes.
if (activeTubes[i] && beardman.x >= activeTubes[i].x)
{
    score++;
    activeTubes[i] = null;
}
```

Or even from a for loop perspective:

```
var i:int;
for ( ; i < activeTubes.length; i++ ) {
    //check if the index is null, if so continue.
    if ( !activeTubes[i] ) { continue; }

    if (beardman.x >= activeTubes[i].x)
    {
        score++;
        activeTubes[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind if you are doing this in a for loop, splicing the array (if you are looping over said array)  during a loop is error prone. Therefore you may want to add a break after the splice.

Comment: Yes, anyways I made a copy of the tubes array and called it markers. Here's my new code and it works fine now, thanks!                      
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{
 if (beardman.x >= markers[i].x)
 {
  score++;
  markers.splice(i, 1);
  break;
 }
}

Comment: I'm going to add some information to the answer, please mark the answer correct if this answers your question.